# looping through a set a urls with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import warnings


urls = ['england/premier-league/brentford-brighton/23ixII53/','england/premier-league/fulham-bournemouth/pStsHxL9/']


for i in urls:
    target_urls = f'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/{i}'
```

is there a way I can make the output of target_urls = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/fulham-bournemouth/pStsHxL9/',
'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/brentford-brighton/23ixII53/'

Been stuck working on this for a while. The loop for x in urls:
print(x) of course works but for working with selenium I need the urls to be more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions:

```py
target_urls = [f"https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/{i}" for i in urls]
```

and you should have

```py
>>> target_urls
['https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/brentford-brighton/23ixII53/',
'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/fulham-bournemouth/pStsHxL9/']
```